# Mule ESB Connector method with Boolean parameter

Tags: java, mule-esb

I have a Mule ESB custom connector with a method that has a Boolean type as a parameter such as:

```
public class MyConnector {
  public Object doSomething(Boolean raining) {
    ....
   return someObject;
  }
}
```

Now when this method "doSomething()" is invoked, I get an exception:

There are two transformers that are an exact match for input:

> org.mule.api.registry.ResolverException: There are two transformers that are an exact match for input: "class java.lang.String", output: "class java.lang.Boolean". Transformers are: "StringToBoolean(class org.mule.transformer.simple.StringToBoolean)" and "StringToBoolean(class org.mule.transformer.simple.StringToBoolean)"

I am not sure how to make this work. Any help appreciated.

Thanks